Algorithm to cluster data points with categorical data and existing labels
Suppose that I have a dataframe of e-commerce product views data, where each row represents a product view and whether it led to conversion (purchase / not purchased)
Sample columns of the data: currencyCode, country, pageType, isMobile, browser, hourOfDay, productPrice, converted.
My goal is to sensibly assign "cohort" to user views using all the features except price (all / most of them are categorical). taking into account the price and label in the data (almost like semi supervised). So that when a new view come in (without price and conversion data), I know which cluster the view belongs to.
The clustering of those views should somehow factor in the influence of productPrice and converted. Wondering what is the best way to cluster those data points?
I know that kprototypes / kmodes exist that handles categorical data, but have not found a way to factor in the influence of price and conversion, also it doesn't take into account the data's label.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/169644/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/654059/2921.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.
